# How can I add button like plus button in message section in Facebook app?

Tags: android

I want to add button that fix position even if I scroll down or up its position doesn't change like the blue plus button at the right bottom of screen.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't kept the button in ScrollView and Download the image of same type in google and set it as background resource for your button..

Comment: For example, set RelativeLayout as a parent then add ScrollView as a child and add this button in RelativeLayout right ?